# Google Maps Integration inside iPhone App

Tags: cocoa-touch, google-maps, iphone-sdk-3.0, mapkit, core-location

I have a question about Google Maps integration inside a iPhone application.

On my application, I have several stores inside a plist. Each store on plist has its altitude and logintude. So, I load each store on the map provided by Google Maps with MapKit.

The problem is I want to say the user what is the store nearest his location. Any of you know how to do it? I know the probable solution is to use Google Maps API or Core Location to find the nearest store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the Core Location to get the user's current location and show all the stores that are 'near' him (whatever near means to you app) using the getDistanceFrom from the core location to calc the distance.

take a look at [this](http://maciejmatyjas.com/2010/05/core-location-and-map-kit-bringing-your-own-maps-voices-that-matter-iphone-2010/) that presents something similar